# Elasticsearch: multi_match no effect with filters

Tags: elasticsearch

I try to be brief. This search does not apply the search keywords present in `multi_match`. Any search text I insert, **I always get the same result**.

If I delete `filtered / filter`, it gives me a proper search. Why?

```
GET /catalog/products/_search
{
   "from":0,
   "size":150,
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "query":{
            "multi_match":{
               "query":"text to search",
               "fields":[
                  "title^5",
                  "description"
               ]
            },
            "filter":{
               "and":[
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "category": 2
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "not":{
                        "term":{
                           "subCategory": 3
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the filter on the same level at query, like this:

```
GET /catalog/products/_search
{
    "from":0,
    "size":150,
    "query":{
      "filtered":{
        "query":{
          "multi_match":{
             "query":"text to search",
             "fields":[
                "title^5",
                "description"
             ]
          }
        },
        "filter":{
           "and":[
              {
                 "term":{
                    "category": 2
                 }
              },
              {
                 "not":{
                    "term":{
                       "subCategory": 3
                    }
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Without your help I would lose the sight to find the problem!